# Flink Table API watermark after a select operation on a table

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm using Flink for processing some streaming data. First of all I have two tables receiving events from Kafka. These tables are joined and the resulting table is converted to a DataStream where it is processed by a custom KeyedProcessFunction. The output is then converted to a table and sent to Opensearch.

```
final TableDescriptor legalFilesTableDescriptor = TableDescriptor.forConnector("kafka")
                .schema(Schema.newBuilder()
                        .column("id", DataTypes.BIGINT())
                        .column("nrg", DataTypes.STRING())
                        .column("ufficio", DataTypes.STRING())
                        .column("sezione", DataTypes.STRING())
                        .column("giudice", DataTypes.STRING())
                        .column("oggetto", DataTypes.STRING())
                        .column("codice_oggetto", DataTypes.STRING())
                        .build())
                .option(KafkaConnectorOptions.TOPIC, List.of("sicid.public.fascicoli"))
                .option(KafkaConnectorOptions.PROPS_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS, KAFKA_HOST)
                .option(KafkaConnectorOptions.SCAN_STARTUP_MODE, KafkaConnectorOptions.ScanStartupMode.LATEST_OFFSET)
                .option(KafkaConnectorOptions.VALUE_FORMAT, "debezium-json")
                .build();
        tEnv.createTable("LegalFilesTable_Kafka", legalFilesTableDescriptor);
        Table legalFilesTable = tEnv.from("LegalFilesTable_Kafka");

    final TableDescriptor eventsTableDescriptor = TableDescriptor.forConnector("kafka")
            .schema(Schema.newBuilder()
                    .column("id", DataTypes.BIGINT())
                    .column("data", DataTypes.BIGINT())
                    .columnByExpression("data_evento", "TO_TIMESTAMP_LTZ(data, 3)")
                    .column("evento", DataTypes.STRING())
                    .column("id_fascicolo", DataTypes.BIGINT())
                    .build())
            .option(KafkaConnectorOptions.TOPIC, List.of("sicid.public.eventi"))
            .option(KafkaConnectorOptions.PROPS_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS, KAFKA_HOST)
            .option(KafkaConnectorOptions.SCAN_STARTUP_MODE, KafkaConnectorOptions.ScanStartupMode.LATEST_OFFSET)
            .option(KafkaConnectorOptions.VALUE_FORMAT, "debezium-json")
            .build();
    tEnv.createTable("EventsTable_Kafka", eventsTableDescriptor);

    Table legalFileEventsTable = legalFilesTable.join(eventsTable)
            .where($("id").isEqual($("id_fascicolo")))
            .select(
                    $("id").as("id_fascicolo"),
                    $("id_evento"),
                    $("giudice"),
                    $("nrg"),
                    $("codice_oggetto"),
                    $("oggetto"),
                    $("ufficio"),
                    $("sezione"),
                    $("data_evento"),
                    $("evento")
            );

    DataStream<Row> phasesDurationsDataStream = tEnv.toChangelogStream(legalFileEventsTable)
            .keyBy(r -> r.<Long>getFieldAs("id_fascicolo"))
            .process(new PhaseDurationCounterProcessFunction())
            .returns(new RowTypeInfo(
                    new TypeInformation[] {
                            BasicTypeInfo.LONG_TYPE_INFO,
                            BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO,
                            BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO,
                            BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO,
                            BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO,
                            BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO,
                            BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO,
                            BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO,
                            BasicTypeInfo.BOOLEAN_TYPE_INFO,
                            BasicTypeInfo.LONG_TYPE_INFO,
                            BasicTypeInfo.INSTANT_TYPE_INFO,
                            BasicTypeInfo.INSTANT_TYPE_INFO
                    },
                    new String[] { "id_fascicolo", "nrg", "giudice", "oggetto", "codice_oggetto",
                            "ufficio", "sezione", "fase", "fase_completata", "durata" , "data_inizio", "data_fine" }
            ));

    final Schema phasesDurationsSchema = Schema.newBuilder()
            .column("id_fascicolo", DataTypes.BIGINT().notNull())
            .column("nrg", DataTypes.STRING())
            .column("giudice", DataTypes.STRING())
            .column("oggetto", DataTypes.STRING())
            .column("codice_oggetto", DataTypes.STRING())
            .column("ufficio", DataTypes.STRING())
            .column("sezione", DataTypes.STRING())
            .column("fase", DataTypes.STRING().notNull())
            .column("fase_completata", DataTypes.BOOLEAN())
            .column("durata", DataTypes.BIGINT())
            .column("data_inizio", DataTypes.TIMESTAMP_LTZ(3))
            .column("data_fine", DataTypes.TIMESTAMP_LTZ(3))
            .primaryKey("id_fascicolo", "fase")
            .build();

    Table phasesDurationsTable = tEnv.fromChangelogStream(phasesDurationsDataStream, phasesDurationsSchema,
            ChangelogMode.upsert());

    final TableDescriptor phasesDurationsOS = TableDescriptor.forConnector("opensearch")
            .schema(phasesDurationsSchema)
            .option(OpensearchConnectorOptions.HOSTS_OPTION, List.of(OPENSEARCH_HOST))
            .option(OpensearchConnectorOptions.INDEX_OPTION, "legal_files_phase_duration")
            .option(OpensearchConnectorOptions.USERNAME_OPTION, "admin")
            .option(OpensearchConnectorOptions.PASSWORD_OPTION, "admin")
            .option(OpensearchConnectorOptions.ALLOW_INSECURE, true)
            .build();
    tEnv.createTable("PhasesDurationsOS", phasesDurationsOS);
```

After that I filter the *phasesDurationTable* like this:

```
    Table filteredPhasesDurationsTable = phasesDurationsTable
            .where($("fase_completata").isTrue())
            .select(
                    $("id_fascicolo"),
                    $("nrg"),
                    $("giudice"),
                    $("oggetto"),
                    $("codice_oggetto"),
                    $("ufficio"),
                    $("sezione"),
                    $("fase"),
                    $("durata"),
                    $("data_inizio"),
                    $("data_fine")
            );
```

With the *filteredPhasesDurationsTable* I need to calculate some averages with a sliding window. So I need to define a watermark on the *data_fine* parameter. Is there a way to do this?